# I have a plugin that applies a Google translation to my page--how does the browser know which language to display?

Tags: plugins, multi-language

My site uses a plugin ([Google Language Translator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/)) to apply a Google translation of the text (see [page here](https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/)--the flags at the top of the page switch the language).  If I change to another language, close the browser, re-open the browser, and re-open my page, the same language is displayed.  How does the browser know to display in the same language as before?

Is there some variable set somewhere?  Perhaps a cookie, or session ID?  Or perhaps some kind of JavaScript variable?  I've looked through the source code, but can't see anything obvious.

I have tried contacting the plugin developer, but they have not responded :-/

The motivation for my question is because I have now used a separate plugin (WPML) to create a manual French translation of my site.  But when a visitor switches between the Google translations and this manual French site, there are issues.  For example, if a visitor switches to Chinese, then tries to access the French site, the page is displayed [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezo2Q.jpg).  On first glance, it appears that the browser continues to think a Chinese Google translation needs to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

The replies in [this outside thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Wordpress/comments/7588pk/plugin_applies_a_google_translation_to_pagehow/) led me to discover that a cookie is indeed being set in the browser that instructs a Google translation to be applied.  This is the information I was after.

edit:  Specifically, the plugin displays the Google Language Bar on my site.  When a visitor uses this language bar to switch the language of the page, a `googtrans` cookie is set on my page, corresponding to the indicated language ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44SLI.jpg)).  As I understand, the cookie is added by an external script hosted by Google, not by the plugin.  So I cannot delete the cookie, or cause it to expire.

Comment: Hi can you please post the snippet that helped you as a link to the page might not work in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanielFlick Done.

Comment: That cookie would be set in the users browser, not on your page (I hope!). Have you seen this? You can tell your page what default languages it supports, might help? https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=en Can you give a url for your page so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: @NathanielFlick Yes, my mistake--the cookie is set in the browser, not on the page.  The URL of the site is:  https://dev.horizonhomes-samui.com/  And I have not seen that Google Translator tool--I will take a look and see if it is viable in my case.  Just to be clear though, I know the answer to my original question.  The overall task is still ongoing.  If you can provide suggestions, that would be great.  But I'm not sure if mods would like it if we continued the conversation in this question.  If you want, that Reddit thread I linked before is still ongoing.

Comment: Ok, also the user normally chooses the language so that should solve it?

Comment: @NathanielFlick I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I can definitely say that my original question is answered.  I'm still working on a solution to my overarching issue:  if a user selects a machine (Google-provided) translation, then changes to the manual translation, there are translation issues.  Conversely, if a user selects the manual translation, then switches to a machine translation, there are translation issues.  This is because selecting a Google translation leaves a particular Google language cookie on the browser, which I need to somehow clear/flush/reset.

Comment: But you are correct in that the user will choose the language.